# How to debug WatchOS app with Companion Ios app using VS Mac or Rider?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to debug my WatchOs app with coupled Ios App. Suggested that start debugging Ios Phone app and automatically should be installed on Apple watch simulator. But following is happening.

I open both simulators Watch and Iphone, I couple them. Apple watch simulator is showing connected.
Once I select Iphone simulator from Rider/VS Mac and start debugging, Watch closes and when I open watch from the toolbar it shows that it is disconnected. I have no chance to connect again. At least visually it shows disconnected but I think that it is not as i can change the watch face from the phone.

Anyhow, under Watch settings on the phone, it shows my app is getting installed on the watch and loading, loading but nothing is happening for mins and then it breaks.
When i manually try to install, it shows that "storage is full on the watch".

I have tried with different simulator combinations and tried to reset bot simulators.
So what is the thing? how people work with WatchOs on Mac using Rider or VS Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finall could figure out what the problem is. In case anyone come across the same issue. Here are the things.
I had similar issue with Xcode and Swiftui as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616313/xcode-14-cannot-install-watchos-app-on-apple-watch-simulator?noredirect=1#comment135093157_76616313)
This helps also Rider and VS for Mac but there are other errors occuring.

Then occurs error as "cannot create bundle" error. there are 2 things to set up here.

1. In the csproj file change    x86_64, default template has i386 for WatchOsApp and WatchOsExtension projects. Change for both.
2. Uncheck "Device specific build" from the Ios project. this check causing error on WatchOs project also for some reason.